# remove swap to create another backup partition

Tags: partitioning

I need windows :(, i use Dual Boot.
I have a space that is not used in HD for having execido on [humerus of the win8 discs. Can I delete my SWAP partition to transform it into a discp backup? I have 8 Gb of memory, my swap partition is 16 gb.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file /etc/fstab like this:

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

And find the line referring to your swap partition. In my case is:

```
/dev/sdb1 none swap sw 0 0
```

And I've commented it to look like this:

```
#/dev/sdb1 none swap sw 0 0
```

After that, reboot your computer and check for a few minutes/hours of normal usage. If it works OK, you can now use gparted to format that swap partition as you like. If you want to use it for windows, I recomend FAT32 or NTFS format.

If you have problems, just revert to the previous state by un-comenting the swap line (that's removing the "#" symbol). And, of course, reformating the partition to swap format.

Comment: In modern Ubuntus, you will find that the UUID of a partition is used to reference it, instead of its device name. For instance, I have `UUID=66713518-d728-4e7b-a703-8538165a3660 none swap sw 0 0`. Don't get confused because it looks a little more complicated, you can comment that out just as described in darent's answer, i.e., just place a `#` in front of the line, yielding something like `#UUID=66713518-d728-4e7b-a703-8538165a3660 none swap sw 0 0`.

Comment: also after deleting the swap you can use a "file" instead of partision as swap

Answer (score 0):

If you sure enough you will not lack of memory then you can delete your swap.but 16 GB for windows installation is little bit to tight for Windows itself

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can be able to delete your 16 GB swap partition to create a backup partition.

All you have to do is,open gparted and then right-click on the swap partition to select swap-off option.After selecting the swap-off option,you can be able to delete that partition.

After that create ntfs partition from the deleted partition.